# Dynamic Tables from user input VS having Attributes and Values stored as Records

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am building an application in which user can define some entities and its characteristics (attributes / fields), as well as relations. Then, he can populate the entities with data.

For example, user can define the following:

1. - *Entity*: Organisation
   - *Attributes*: Id, Name, Location etc
2. - *Entity*: Vehicle
   - *Attributes*: Id, Make, Type etc
   - *BelongsTo*: Organisation

If the above schema was fixed, we could easily implement it in a relational database. However, the schema is dynamically created by the admin user (the good news is that it will not be *that* dynamic, it will be set and only changed if needed).

I am considering the following 2 alternatives:

- Having the tables and their fields being created dynamically. For example, when user inserts *Organisation* entity, the `entity_organisation` (and its fields) table will be created. The same procedure for every entity the user inserts.
- Having the following tables:

  `entities (id, name, ...)`, `fields (id, name, type, entity_id)`, `values (id, value, field_id)`

  When the user defines a new entity, this will be inserted in `entities` table and its fields, accordingly in `fields` table. When the entity is being populated with data, the values will be stored in values table.

I am pretty sure that creating tables dynamically by user input is not a good idea (even if it is by the admin). However, the second approach comes with some problems: 1) many joins, 2) the `value` column of `values` table can be any type, according to `type` column of `fields` table. Therefore, in this approach I may have to create all possible columns (value_int, value_text, value_boolean etc).

Any ideas? What would be the best approach?

P.S. I want to stick with Postgres (noSQL is not an option)

Comment: 1. Don't do EAV 2. Some SO questions/answers that may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304217/database-schema-which-can-support-specialized-properties/4359193#4359193 (model diagram may be particularly insightful) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011956/single-fixed-table-with-multiple-columns-vs-flexible-abstract-tables/4013207#4013207

Comment: I would also add: having the specific entities and relations fixed (with well defined keys) with certain *attributes* optional/varying is a far easier approach.  Alternatively, define common "entities" as traditional DB tables, have a 6NF or other approach for custom or user-defined "entities."

Comment: One possibility is a sort of "hybrid" design: have common attributes defined as regular columns, and have anything variable/dynamic defined as a JSON type.